# Mapping Exception with Hibernate 4.0, UserType 3.0.0.CR4 and Joda Time 2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime, usertype

I am currently trying to persist Joda Time in Hibernate using [usertype](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/), but I keep on getting the following error in eclipse.

[image: Error Message]

(failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.jsr310.PersistentLocalDateTime, at table: MODEL_OBJECT, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(MODIFIED_DATE_TIME)])

my xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="model" >
    <class name="ModelObject" table="MODEL_OBJECT">
        <id name="id" column="MODEL_ID" >
            <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="modifiedDateTime"             
            type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.jsr310.PersistentLocalDateTime"
            column="MODIFIED_DATE_TIME"/>
        <property name="creationDateTime"
            type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.jsr310.PersistentLocalDateTime"
            column="CREATION_DATE_TIME"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>`
```

and my java file looks like this

```
package model;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

public abstract class ModelObject  {

private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

private long id;
private LocalDateTime  modifiedDateTime = new LocalDateTime ();
private LocalDateTime  creationDateTime = new LocalDateTime ();

public Long getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id){
    firePropertyChange("id", this.id, this.id = id);
}

public LocalDateTime  getModifiedDateTime(){
    return modifiedDateTime;
}

public void setModifiedDateTime(LocalDateTime  modifiedDateTime) {
    firePropertyChange("modifiedDateTime", 
                this.modifiedDateTime, 
                this.modifiedDateTime = modifiedDateTime);
}

public LocalDateTime  getCreationDateTime(){
    return creationDateTime;
}

public void setCreationDateTime(LocalDateTime  creationDateTime){
    firePropertyChange("creationDateTime", 
                this.creationDateTime, 
                this.creationDateTime = creationDateTime);
}

public void addPropertyChangeSupportListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
    changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
    changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener){
    changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, 
                                             PropertyChangeListener listener){
    changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
}

protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue){
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
}

}
```

I have added usertype.spi-3.0.0.jar and usertype.core.3.0.0.CR3.jar to my class path.

I have no idea what is going on here so help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add separate file with HBM custom types
`CustomTypes.hbm.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.softcomputer.softlab.business.core">
   <typedef name="localJodaDate"
      class="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.jsr310.PersistentLocalDateTime" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

include this file to your mapping

```
  <mapping resource="CustomTypes.hbm.xml" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I' still get the same error as I did before. I've updated my question to contain a print screen of the error in eclipse if that is any help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It seems if I make a custom type I can skip out UserType completely which seems to fix my error.

<hibernate-mapping package="model.entity">
   <typedef name="localJodaDate"
      class="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime" />
</hibernate-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the JSR 310 types (for threeten) rather than the Joda Time types.

Change org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.jsr310.PersistentLocalDateTime to org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime and your problem should be resolved.

Regards Chris